# Case stament with same conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I wanted to know when "ONE" (Capital) will get printed in below code??

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTCASE
@ID bigint 
AS DECLARE
@VAR bigint     
BEGIN

SELECT 
CASE @ID 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'One'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Two'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ONE'
END

END


EXEC TESTCASE 1
```

Comment: It won't. Perhaps it would help if you told us what you were trying to achieve...

Comment: Yes its getting compiled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will never be printed. When `ID` is 1, the first `WHEN` will be executed and the case statement will exit.

Comment: Even I thought the same, But in previously written code i found similar to this code... hence i thought it can be like no break after Case 1 then go ahead and check for case 2 .. which is the case in C..